# LinuxMint 20.3: Enter the Login Keyring password via the command line

Tags: linux-mint, terminal, password, gnome-keyring, seahorse

#Refer: [How to enter the Default Keyring password via the command line? - Ask Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/18927/how-to-enter-the-default-keyring-password-via-the-command-line)

I am asking this question here as I am not using Ubuntu and also the solution mentioned there doesn't work in LinuxMint 20.3

---

```bsh
$ whoami
nikhil
pip install keyring
```

I created an executable python script as follows:

```py
import keyring
import getpass

keyring.set_password('login', 'nikhil', getpass.getpass('Password: '));
```

On executing the script and entering the password, the Login keyring still remains locked. Any suggestions?

## Reference

1. [getpass — Portable password input — Python 3.10.2 documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/getpass.html)
2. [keyring · PyPI](https://pypi.org/project/keyring/)